# how to interpolate a matrix into desired size?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to interpolate a 58:2 matrix into 57:1 matrix.

Actually I want to solve

```
(A(t)-P2i(t))v(t)=dv/dt
```

I have p2i size as `57:1.A=[0 1;a0 a1]` where `a0` and `a1` are also time varying. After interpolating size of `a0` and `a1` are `57:1` so now the size of A became `58:1`. I am trying to solve above equation using ode45 but couldn't because dimensions of A and p2i are different.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Slow down, show what the actual error message is, and tell us the actual size of each variable.   `A` can't be `58x1`, because you catenated two columns together.

Comment: It gives error as below ??? Error using ==> minus
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Answer (score 0):

The difference: A(t)-P2i(t) is not defined

You could try taking a submatrix of A, or padding P2i with some zeroes.

If you want to interpolate this matrix you could consider defining a new matrix M where M(i,:) = (A(i,:) + A(i+1,:)) / 2